# Object rendering looks bad in Tikz-3dplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3dplot

I am trying to make some drawing using `tikz-3dplot`,  similar to below image where the axis is perendicular to the cuboid planes.

[image]

However, in my case, the axes appear to be significantly misaligned with the cuboid face. It could be due to a rendering issue or perhaps I am doing something terribly wrong. Is there any way to correct this problem?
[image]

Here is the snip:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz, tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, arrows.meta}
\tikzset{
mycube/.style ={
color = black!80,
fill = blue!50,
line width = 0.2pt,
rounded corners=1.5pt,
opacity=0.8
  }
}
% Defining the cuboid with a bottom left corner at (x,y,z) cordinate and length, width     
\newcommand{\cube}[6]{
\pgfmathsetmacro{\cubelength}{#4}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\cubewidth}{#5}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\cubethickness}{#6}
\draw[mycube, tdplot_main_coords] (#1,#2,#3) -- ++(0,\cubewidth,0) -- ++(0,0, \cubethickness) -- ++(0, -\cubewidth, 0) -- cycle;
\draw[mycube, shift = {(-\cubelength, 0, 0)}, tdplot_main_coords] (#1,#2,#3) -- ++(0,\cubewidth,0) -- ++(0,0, \cubethickness) -- ++(0, -\cubewidth, 0) -- cycle;
\draw[mycube, tdplot_main_coords] (#1,#2,#3) -- ++(-\cubelength,0,0) -- ++(0,0, \cubethickness) -- ++(\cubelength, 0, 0) -- cycle;
\draw[mycube, shift = {(0, \cubewidth, 0)}, tdplot_main_coords] (#1,#2,#3) -- ++(-\cubelength,0,0) -- ++(0,0, \cubethickness) -- ++(\cubelength, 0, 0) -- cycle;
\draw[mycube, tdplot_main_coords] (#1,#2,#3) -- ++(-\cubelength,0,0) -- ++(0,\cubewidth, 0) -- ++(\cubelength, 0, 0) -- cycle;
\draw[mycube, shift = {(0, 0, \cubethickness)}, tdplot_main_coords] (#1,#2,#3) -- ++(-\cubelength,0,0) -- ++(0,\cubewidth, 0) -- ++(\cubelength, 0, 0) -- cycle;
 }
%
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{75}{130}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,tdplot_main_coords]
% Defining the axis
\draw[>=triangle 45, ->, tdplot_main_coords,] (1.3, 0,0 ) -- (2, 0, 0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};
\draw[>=triangle 45, ->, tdplot_main_coords,] (0, 0,0 ) -- (0, 2, 0) node[anchor=north east]{$y$};
\draw[>=triangle 45, ->, tdplot_main_coords,] (0, 0,0 ) -- (0, 0, 2) node[anchor=north east]{$z$};
\draw[>=triangle 45, ->, tdplot_main_coords,] (0, 0,0 ) -- (-2, 0, 0) node[anchor=north east]{$-x$};
\draw[>=triangle 45, ->, tdplot_main_coords,] (0, 0,0 ) -- (0, -2, 0) node[anchor=north east]{$-y$};
\draw[>=triangle 45, ->, tdplot_main_coords,] (0, 0,0 ) -- (0, 0, -1) node[anchor=north east]{$-z$};
%Draw the cuboid
%\cube{x}{y}{z}{legth}{width}{thickness}
%
\cube{1}{-1}{-0.1}{2}{2}{0.2}
\end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to make the image better is to draw the positive axis after the cube and adjust the initial points:

[image]

##Code:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz, tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, arrows.meta}
\tikzset{
mycube/.style ={
color = black!80,
fill = blue!50,
line width = 0.2pt,
rounded corners=1.5pt,
opacity=0.8
  }
}
% Defining the cuboid with a bottom left corner at (x,y,z) cordinate and length, width     
\newcommand{\cube}[6]{
\pgfmathsetmacro{\cubelength}{#4}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\cubewidth}{#5}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\cubethickness}{#6}
\draw[mycube, tdplot_main_coords, red] (#1,#2,#3) -- ++(0,\cubewidth,0) -- ++(0,0, \cubethickness) -- ++(0, -\cubewidth, 0) -- cycle;
\draw[mycube, shift = {(-\cubelength, 0, 0)}, tdplot_main_coords] (#1,#2,#3) -- ++(0,\cubewidth,0) -- ++(0,0, \cubethickness) -- ++(0, -\cubewidth, 0) -- cycle;
\draw[mycube, tdplot_main_coords] (#1,#2,#3) -- ++(-\cubelength,0,0) -- ++(0,0, \cubethickness) -- ++(\cubelength, 0, 0) -- cycle;
\draw[mycube, shift = {(0, \cubewidth, 0)}, tdplot_main_coords] (#1,#2,#3) -- ++(-\cubelength,0,0) -- ++(0,0, \cubethickness) -- ++(\cubelength, 0, 0) -- cycle;
\draw[mycube, tdplot_main_coords] (#1,#2,#3) -- ++(-\cubelength,0,0) -- ++(0,\cubewidth, 0) -- ++(\cubelength, 0, 0) -- cycle;
\draw[mycube, shift = {(0, 0, \cubethickness)}, tdplot_main_coords] (#1,#2,#3) -- ++(-\cubelength,0,0) -- ++(0,\cubewidth, 0) -- ++(\cubelength, 0, 0) -- cycle;
 }
%
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{75}{130}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,tdplot_main_coords]
% Defining the negative axis
\draw[>=triangle 45, ->, tdplot_main_coords,] (0, 0,0 ) -- (-2, 0, 0) node[anchor=north east]{$-x$};
\draw[>=triangle 45, ->, tdplot_main_coords,] (0, 0,0 ) -- (0, -2, 0) node[anchor=north east]{$-y$};
\draw[>=triangle 45, ->, tdplot_main_coords,] (0, 0,0 ) -- (0, 0, -1) node[anchor=north east]{$-z$};

%Draw the cuboid
%\cube{x}{y}{z}{legth}{width}{thickness}
\cube{1}{-1}{-0.1}{2}{2}{0.2}

% Defining the positive negative axis
\draw[>=triangle 45, ->, tdplot_main_coords,] (1.1, 0,0 ) -- (2, 0, 0) node[anchor=north east]{$x$};
\draw[>=triangle 45, ->, tdplot_main_coords,] (0, 1.1,0 ) -- (0, 2, 0) node[anchor=north east]{$y$};
\draw[>=triangle 45, ->, tdplot_main_coords,] (0, 0, 0.1 ) -- (0, 0, 1) node[anchor=north east]{$z$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```